# Boolean changes value before I can assign it

Tags: objective-c, spotify

I have a curious problem where my boolean variable is changing before I can assign it to a variable to be read in my react native code for Spotify SDK.

I have pinpointed the EXACT location as to where it changes and I am currently trying to figure out why:

I have a boolean called `isLoggedIn` that is set equal to 1 if a successful login occurs. This variable then sets `loggedIn` to a boolean value which is sent to my React Native code:

```
else
{
    // login successful
    NSLog(@"What is the value of isLoggedIn %@", [self isLoggedIn]);
    ////THIS shows that isLoggedIn still equal to 1.
    [self initializePlayerIfNeeded:[RNSpotifyCompletion onComplete:^(id unused, RNSpotifyError* unusedError) {
        NSLog(@"What is the value of isLoggedIn right after %@", [self isLoggedIn]);
        /////NOW the isLoggedIn variable is now equal to 0.


        // do UI logic on main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [authController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                _loggingIn = NO;
                NSLog(@"What is the value of isLoggedIn %@", [self isLoggedIn]);
                NSNumber* loggedIn = [self isLoggedIn]; /////this is the line we need to be == 1
                resolve(loggedIn);
                if(loggedIn.boolValue)
                {
                    [self sendEvent:@"login" args:@[]];
                }
            }];
        });
    }]];
}
```

So obviously I assume that it is due to this line right?:

```
[self initializePlayerIfNeeded:[RNSpotifyCompletion onComplete:^(id unused, RNSpotifyError* unusedError)
```

Which is running this method: `initializePlayerIfNeeded` but when I read the value of the isLoggedIn variable at the end of this method it still shows a boolean value of 1 (look at last line):

```
-(void)initializePlayerIfNeeded:(RNSpotifyCompletion*)completion
{

    if(![self hasPlayerScope])
    {
        [completion resolve:nil];
        return;
    }

    // ensure only one thread is invoking the initialization at a time
    BOOL initializedPlayer = NO;
    NSError* error = nil;
    BOOL allowCaching = (_cacheSize.unsignedIntegerValue > 0);
    @synchronized(_player)
    {
        // check if player is already initialized
        if(_player.initialized)
        {
            initializedPlayer = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            initializedPlayer = [_player startWithClientId:_auth.clientID audioController:nil allowCaching:allowCaching error:&error];
        }
    }

    // handle initialization failure
    if(!initializedPlayer)
    {
        [completion reject:[RNSpotifyError errorWithNSError:error]];
        return;
    }

    // setup player
    _player.delegate = self;
    _player.playbackDelegate = self;
    if(allowCaching)
    {
        _player.diskCache = [[SPTDiskCache alloc] initWithCapacity:_cacheSize.unsignedIntegerValue];
    }

    // attempt to log in the player
    [self loginPlayer:completion];

    NSLog(@"What is the value of isLoggedIn %@", [self isLoggedIn]);
    ////THIS shows that isLoggedIn still equal to 1.

}
```

So that method finishes up with the value still equal to 1, but why after that method returns does the next line show that `isLoggedIn` equal to 0? I am extremely new to objC so every bit of knowledge is helpful for me. I am using this React Native Spotify library from github: https://github.com/lufinkey/react-native-spotify

You can find the exact file I'm working with here: https://github.com/lufinkey/react-native-spotify/blob/master/ios/RNSpotify.m

What else would you need to help solve this?

EDIT: here's the method that changes the `isLoggedIn`:

```
RCT_EXPORT_BLOCKING_SYNCHRONOUS_METHOD(isLoggedIn)
{

    if(!_initialized)
    {
        return @NO;
    }
    else if(_auth.session == nil)
    {
        return @NO;
    }
    return @YES;
}
```

Comment: I think you've confused `_loggingIn = NO;` for `isLoggedIn`... If not, show the function that sets `isLoggedIn`. It looks like your call it multiple times and it's probably acting as a switch every time.

Comment: @l'L'l hmm I don't think I am..I've added the code that sets isLoggedIn for you!

Comment: Is `isLoggedIn` a variable, a property or a method? Will `isLoggedIn` return a different value when `_auth.session` changes?

Comment: @Willeke from my understanding, `isLoggedIn` is a method and from the code I edited in, it appears that changing `auth.session` does affect the boolean output

Comment: What does `if(_auth.session == nil)` do?

Comment: I'm trying to figure that out as well. If you have 5-10 minutes, he has set up an example app in his repo, however running that I have the same issue, do you encounter the same problem where after you log in it just sends you back to the log in screen? https://github.com/lufinkey/react-native-spotify @Willeke